# in zebra datepicker how can i get or extract week number from selected date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

below is my attempt, but it doesn't work.  the first line is to initialize the datepicker, then there are some options that can be set, then in the onSelect section is how i was trying to get the selected and convert to a week number, then for testing i was just trying to alert the week number.  once i get it to work i will put the week number somewhere for use.

```
$("input#someid").Zebra_DatePicker({
format: 'm-d-Y',
direction: 1,
show_clear_date: 'FALSE',
onSelect: function(view, elements) { //when a date is selected
    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
    }
    var myvariable = $( "#someid" ).val();
    var weekno = myvariable.getWeek();
    alert(weekno);
}
});
```

the format of the date matters.  it needs to be able to convert from m-d-Y (01-13-2014) format to a week number.  so for example, today's date would have a result of 3 because it's the 3rd week of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Zebra_DatePicker, that it gives the week number or not but Even if it does not give you the week number directly you can simply work it out yourself if you have the day and the month...for example this way

```
week = math.ceil((month * day)/7);
```

This will give you week of the year. On the other hand if you are unable to get even the day and month then get it through splitting the date.

```
var now = new Date(document.getElementById('element_id').value);//replace the element_id with actual input id of the zebra datepicker

//var now = new Date("02-01-2014");//hard coded date
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
var week = Math.ceil(day/7);
alert(week);
```

Cheers

P.S. Assuming that the third week starts from 15th right?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link for you 

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadnawaz121/gpSLK/18/)

Comment: seems to work, but would it change the formula if 3rd week starts on the 12th?

Comment: Yes definitely. It is all in your hand. I counted the week by keeping in mind 7 days a week thing. I divided by 7. It is upto you, like you can use 5 or 6 or even 5.5 according to your choice in order to get the desired results...let me know if you have any confusion...

Comment: If you replace 7 by 5.5, it will give you week 3 on 12th and week 2 on 11th. Let me know if you have any other confusions so that I can clear them out for you...cheers :)

Comment: getting weird results.  january seems good, but february is not calculating right.  getting week 1 for feb 1st when it should be week 5. feb 3 is week 2 instead of week 6.  feb 10 is week 4 instead of 7.  actually looking back at january, it's only right until 22nd day.  from jan 23 it starts calculating wrong week number.

Comment: I have updated the code. Now we are using proper date object and then calculating the week number from there on. Again I used 7 days for a week. Took Help From [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bm7GJ/)...It works fine for me...

Comment: i get Nan as the text that gets alerted.  also having trouble making new Date(); use a hard coded date, but really the hard coded date is variable from an input field value.  if you alert "now" from now = new Date(); you get "Wed Jan 15 2014 11:08:44 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)".  putting a 3 part date in there, like this: var now = new Date("02-01-2014"); doesn't match up to the long version of date.  i also tried moving getFullYear so it's the 3rd parameter like this: var start = new Date(0, 0, now.getFullYear()); but that didn't work either.

Comment: so lets say i make variable from date inserted from date picker like this: var date = $( "#filter3" ).val(); then i change the now line to look like this: var now = new Date(date);  then i try to alert the now variable: alert(now); the alert popup says "invalid date".  date format is m-d-Y or mm-dd-YYYY or 01-15-2014.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45310/discussion-between-leoarce-and-ahmad-nawaz)

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding. I used the format that the Zebra DatePicker uses. Check the link [here](http://annaswardrobe.net/zebra_date_demo/)..In the input box, select the date you want and then click the check week number..it will alert the week number...Kindly check and let me know if it is ok? Basically I just changed the code a little to get the input date from the zebra datepicker. Let me know...